# Extract link and word from word file

Tags: ms-word

I have Word file contains 10000+ lines among them 4503 words are blue & red colored. I want to extract all those blue and red colored word with its links.
As I have shown in image the link are on various number. And word are written before it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace/ Format/ Font/ Font color: Automatic (or black)/ OK

Replace with ^p

Replace all.